# Why is T test reweighting on a word X word co-occurrence matrix so effective?

Tags: nlp, statistics, word-embeddings, stanford-nlp

I am going through Stanford NLP class: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224u/

A task in the homework is to implement T-test reweighting on a word X word co-occurrence matrix: 
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/cgpotts/cs224u/blob/2019-spring/hw1_wordsim.ipynb#t-test-reweighting-[2-points]

$$\textbf{ttest}(X, i, j) = 
\frac{
    P(X, i, j) - \big(P(X, i, *)P(X, *, j)\big)
}{
\sqrt{(P(X, i, *)P(X, *, j))}
}$$

I have 2 questions:

- What is the intuition behind this formula? It looks a little like PMI but I can't understand what it's doing. The T-test explanation out there seems to be unrelated to this task.
- It works amazingly well (when evaluated by [this test](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/cgpotts/cs224u/blob/2019-spring/hw1_wordsim.ipynb#Full-evaluation)): raw matrix yield a correlation score of 0.014, PMIed matrix 0.123 and t scored matrix: 0.408979. This number seems almost too good to be true for such a simple model. Can anyone bring some intuition/experience about why that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. IT is very similiar to PMI, here you just expand it to the whole dictionary matrix (matrix representation of the whole vocabulary), normalize it by subtracting quantitive representation of the sum of words found in row i column j and than standardize. (Like when using sklearn Standardize(), similiar atleast)
2. Intuition? Well why is tf-idf working (generally as text quantification technique), you are focusing on essential n-grams and minimising away the rest, with this re-weighting you are getting close to tf-idf representation in a sence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would you explain the square root in the denominator?

Comment: The standard deviation is the square root of the variance, standard deviation is expressed in the same units as the mean is, whereas the variance is expressed in squared units.

Comment: it may because I have very little knowledge of statistics but I can't see why standard deviation brings anything in this equation. (I would normally move on, but it yields such great results that it seems important to get a good grasp on )

Comment: I was refering to the analogy between normalisation of your data and constructing this matrix. You would use same division of a unit square of a measure (for example variance). Benefit is as I said you are not comapering apples with oranges (square root with standard unit) BUT this wont make or break a transformation, main thing is the other parts, and if you dont draw a square root it should not make or break you (does not mean it wont!)